# Android accessibility focus - clicking a view changes focus to previous view

Tags: android, onclick, focus, accessibility

I'm using android TalkBack to test my application for accessibility use.  When I swipe to select a view and double tap, the focus returns the the view above it.  Usually when swiping to a view and double clicking it, onClick is called.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/all_white"
>
<ImageView   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/header"
    android:scaleType="center"
/>
<ImageView   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green_bar"
    android:scaleType="center"
/>  
<ImageView   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blue_bar"
    android:scaleType="center"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="325dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/password"
 />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="325dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/username"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/login"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:onClick="doLogin"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="325dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/password"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/create_trial_account"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/create_trial_account"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_user"
    android:onClick="createAccount"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/login"
 />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/copyright"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/copyright"
  />        
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/buildNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is happening consistently throughout the program where I have to focus on a different view to gain focus on the view I want to click.  Specifically I have to focus on a view below the one I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was caused by setting android:anyDensity to false in the Manifest supports-screens tag.  Once I removed the attribute it worked as expected.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a framework bug. Which version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: This issue showed up on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.1.1.  I haven't tested for this bug on other devices.